# How can I calculate how many working days are to a determined date?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I need to make something like a working days counter, but I don't know how:

Let's say someone makes a request today 04-25-2019 and it needs to be approved on 15 working days, that would be around 05-16-2019, how can this be done? I have no idea yet, and I should include the holidays of my country.

Which would be:

```
01-01-2019
19-04-2019
20-04-2019
01-05-2019
21-05-2019
29-06-2019
16-07-2019
15-08-2019
18-09-2019
19-09-2019
20-09-2019
12-10-2019
31-10-2019
01-11-2019
08-12-2019
25-12-2019
```

I tried this:

```
<%
DateFrom = "10/1/2012"
DateTo = "10/31/2012"
Weekends = 0
ActualDays = 0

' Step 1: Get the actual days
ActualDays = DateDiff("d", DateFrom, DateTo)

' Step 2: Find the weekends
For x = 0 To ActualDays - 1
    xDate = DateAdd("d", x, DateFrom)
    If Weekday(xDate, 1) = 1 Or Weekday(xDate, 1) = 7 Then
        Weekends = Weekends + 1
    End If
Next

WorkingDays = ActualDays - Weekends

response.Write "ActualDays: "&ActualDays  &" Weekends: "& Weekends &" WorkingDays: "& WorkingDays
%>
```

but it didn't work out as I desired.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of the proposed dup-target. While it's close, this question is very explicitly asking for working days (and provided a list of holidays), while the proposed duplicate is calculating weekdays. Weekdays and workdays are not the same thing. While you do need to calculate the number of weekdays in order to determine workdays, there is more to it than just calculating weekdays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right tracks, you just need to check for national holidays aswell (if it's not a weekend) and subtract weekends and national holidays from the actual days count to get the number of working days. Try this:

```
' You need to keep a record of national holidays and keep it updated. Probably best to do this
' outside of your function. You can't use a constant to store an array, you could just dim a 
' regular variable, but IMO a better alternative would be to use "Application" and set it in  
' your global.asa file under "Sub Application_OnStart"... or just use a database.

Application("NationalHolidays") = array("01-01-2019","19-04-2019","20-04-2019","01-05-2019","21-05-2019","29-06-2019","16-07-2019","15-08-2019","18-09-2019","19-09-2019","20-09-2019","12-10-2019","31-10-2019","01-11-2019","08-12-2019","25-12-2019")


function calcDays(fromDate,toDate)

    Dim ActualDays, Weekends, NationalHolidays, WorkingDays, nhIndex, x, y

    fromDate = cDate(fromDate)
    toDate = cDate(toDate)

    ActualDays = DateDiff("d",fromDate,toDate)      
    Weekends = 0    
    NationalHolidays = 0
    WorkingDays = 0
    nhIndex = 0

    ' Loop from start day to end day

    for x = 0 to ActualDays + 1

        ' Count the weekends

        if WeekDay(DateAdd("d",x,fromDate)) = 1 OR WeekDay(DateAdd("d",x,fromDate)) = 7 then
            Weekends = Weekends + 1
        else

            ' Check for national holidays if it's not a weekend

            if NOT nhIndex > uBound(Application("NationalHolidays")) then
                for y = nhIndex to uBound(Application("NationalHolidays"))
                    ' This if/else logic assumes Application("NationalHolidays") is in ascending order.
                    if DateAdd("d",x,fromDate) = cDate(Application("NationalHolidays")(y)) then
                        NationalHolidays = NationalHolidays + 1
                        ' Keep track of the last national holiday found and start from that 
                        ' position + 1 on the next check.
                        nhIndex = y + 1
                        exit for
                    elseif cDate(Application("NationalHolidays")(y)) < DateAdd("d",x,fromDate) then
                        ' Keep count of national holidays that have already passed and skip them
                        ' on the next check.
                        nhIndex = y + 1
                    elseif cDate(Application("NationalHolidays")(y)) > DateAdd("d",x,fromDate) then
                        ' The national holiday dates have exceeded the current date, there's no
                        ' point in continuing checking.
                        exit for
                    end if
                next
            end if

        end if

    next

    ' Working days is the number of days between "fromDate" and "toDate" minus weekends and national holidays

    WorkingDays = (ActualDays-Weekends-NationalHolidays)

    calcDays = "<p>Actual Days: " & ActualDays & "</p>" &_
    "<p>National Holidays: " & NationalHolidays & "</p>" &_
    "<p>Weekends: " & Weekends & "</p>" &_
    "<p>Working Days: " & WorkingDays & "</p>"

end function

response.write calcDays("29-04-2019","13-05-2019")
```

> **April 29th 2019** to **May 13th 2019**

Output:

> Actual Days: 14
> National Holidays: 1
> Weekends: 4
> Working Days: 9

**EDIT:** To calculate `Date X` + `Y Working Days` = `Date Z` (as asked in your question), you can use this function:

```
function AddWorkingDays(startDate,workingDays)

    startDate = cDate(startDate)

    Dim DayCount, workingDayCount, nhIndex, isNationalHoliday, x

    DayCount = 0
    workingDayCount = 0
    nhIndex = 0

    do until workingDayCount = workingDays

        ' Make sure it's not a weekend

        if NOT(WeekDay(DateAdd("d",DayCount,startDate)) = 1 OR WeekDay(DateAdd("d",DayCount,startDate)) = 7) then

            isNationalHoliday = false ' default

            ' Make sure it's not a national holiday

            if NOT nhIndex > uBound(Application("NationalHolidays")) then
                for x = nhIndex to uBound(Application("NationalHolidays"))
                    ' This if/else logic assumes Application("NationalHolidays") is in ascending order.
                    if DateAdd("d",DayCount,startDate) = cDate(Application("NationalHolidays")(x)) then
                        isNationalHoliday = true
                        ' Keep track of the last national holiday found and start from that 
                        ' position + 1 on the next check.
                        nhIndex = x + 1
                        exit for
                    elseif cDate(Application("NationalHolidays")(x)) < DateAdd("d",DayCount,startDate) then
                        ' Keep count of national holidays that have already passed and skip them
                        ' on the next check.
                        nhIndex = x + 1
                    elseif cDate(Application("NationalHolidays")(x)) > DateAdd("d",DayCount,startDate) then
                        ' The national holiday dates have exceeded the current date, there's no
                        ' point in continuing checking.
                        exit for
                    end if
                next
            end if

            if NOT isNationalHoliday then workingDayCount = workingDayCount + 1 ' It's a working day!

        end if

        ' Keep count of the total number of days needed to make up the working day target

        DayCount = DayCount + 1

    loop

    AddWorkingDays = DateAdd("d",DayCount,startDate)

end function

' As in your question, calculate 15 working days from April 25th 2019
response.write AddWorkingDays("25-04-2019",15)
```

> **April 25th 2019** + **15 Working Days**

Output:

> May 17th 2019

Comment: hi @Adam and thanks for your reply, the code you posted as reply to my question is awesome and works great but to complete my task i'm only missing 2 things :1-print the total date and change the number of working days to 15, i need to have 15 working days instead of 15 total days, how can i do this?

Comment: @сꝛıϻѕοɴ ᴠᴇɴoϻ So in your original question you wanted to add 15 working days to April 25th 2019? I think I've come up with a solution, see my updated answer

Comment: it worked!! just what i needed! thanks for your help :D

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. I updated the code again to optimize the National Holidays array search. I've included some code comments to explain the if/else logic. The original code I posted is still fine, but the updated version is just a bit more efficient.